# Font awesome 5 on pseudo elements

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-5

In font awesome 4 you could easily apply an icon to a :before/:after element using CSS.

Is the same possible with the new font awesome 5 JS/SVG implementation? As from what i can see this requires the relevant  tag to exist in html which isn't always practical e.g. you have a CMS and want to apply an icon to all user created content `<li>` elements

I know in FA5 you can still use the old css/webfonts but it would be nice if the same functionality was available in the recommended method of using JS

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to enable it (it's disabled by default).

```
<script>
  window.FontAwesomeConfig = {
    searchPseudoElements: true
  }
</script>
```

Css:

```
.class:before{
  display: none;
  content: "\f16c";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
}
```

Other types:
Font Awesome 5 + Solid or Regular or Light or Brands

Comment: Cheers I saw that searchPseudoElements in the API but it didn't give an example for the font family/content on the site

Comment: I believe this is only if you are using the JS+SVG version of FA.  If you are just using CSS, then @Mohammed's answer is what you need.

Comment: Be careful with this, it can absolutely annihilate performance when using Edge / IE - see https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/12994

Answer (score 168):

Specifying the proper **`font-weight`** seems key to have some of the symbols displayed properly (and not "□□□" instead).

**`font-weight`** has to be:

- **`400`** for `Regular` and `Brands` symbols
- **`900`** for `Solid` symbols
- **`300`** for `Light` symbols

I.e. if you use Font-Awesome with CSS + Webfonts, a CSS-only solution is:

```css
@import url("font-awesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css"); /* FA CSS import */

/* ... */

.class:before {
    /* >> Symbol you want to use: */
    content: "\f16c";
    /* >> Name of the FA free font (mandatory), e.g.:
               - 'Font Awesome 5 Free' for Regular and Solid symbols;
               - 'Font Awesome 5 Pro' for Regular and Solid symbols (Professional License);
               - 'Font Awesome 5 Brand' for Brands symbols. */
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    /* >> Weight of the font (mandatory):
               - 400 for Regular and Brands symbols;
               - 900 for Solid symbols;
               - 300 for Light symbols. */
    font-weight: 900;

    /* >> Optional styling: */
    display: inline-block;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: wow, that should have been part of the official documentation... you saved my day, thx

Comment: Same here. If you're upgrading from an old version of FA, you **need to set the font-weight in all classes containing "content"

Comment: Why isn't this more prominent in the official documentation?  I wasted an entire day trying to figure this out!  :|

Comment: What does `font-weight` do? I am only using the solid icons and `font-weight` seems to have no effect. I can omit it, or set its value to 400 or 900, I always see the icon as expected.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Why all the documentations has to be a piece of trash and not including such important infos?!!

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements it is stated. But most I think will see the font weight specified and ignore it, thinking it's not important (aka, I did).

Comment: here is a cookie @Aldream

Comment: super helpful! this should be on their page! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 20):

I think its working fine just like this:

```
.class:before{
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: font-weight: 900; is only needed for "solid" icons it think.

Answer (score 11):

I got 5 to work using

```
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in `<head>` and

```
:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
  font-weight: 400;
  content: "\f167";
}
```

in my css

Answer (score 6):

Font Awesome 5, all top answers not working in my case as I am using the free version. 
The correct answer for this is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894414/the-before-pseudo-element-not-working-in-font-awesome-v-5).
check your font type (free or pro) then follow:

**Free**

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"
```

**Pro**

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro"
```

**Brands**

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands"
```

Don't forget that I just used the link tag with path to my CSS file in HTML.
No enabling required also didn't import the all.css file to my css file. Now it is working!

Answer (score 2):

Use this Link ->: https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css

```
CSS

ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

ul li:before{
  position: absolute;
  color:#ff0000;
  top:0;
  left:-30px;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-size:1.2em;
  content: "\f105";
  font-weight: 900; /* <-- add this or 400 for other styles */
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: font-weight matters, but I'm not gonna squint through that minified css sheet. They should really include the font-weight  for the icons. Their icon pages include the html and unicode but no info on font-weights https://fontawesome.com/icons/check?style=solid

Comment: However they have a table here  https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements. I experimented with font-weights for the check solid and I could go down to 600.

Answer (score 2):

My problem disappear when i set this value: font-weight: 900;

Answer (score 1):

Should you be using [Fort Awesome](https://fortawesome.com) to serve your icons then you need to add `font-family: <my-kit-name>`, no need to use `font-weight: 400/900`.

For more info see this link:

https://articles.fortawesome.com/how-to-using-fort-awesome-icons-f50ab11a2d2a