# Font Awesome 5 font-family issue

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome-5

I integrated Font Awesome 5 in a project with bootstrap 4. When I recall a font via CSS it does not work.
with Font Awesome 4 the code was as follows:

```
#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse:after {
  float: right;
  content: "\f107";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}
```

I tried to change the font name but it does not work

```
font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free'
```

Comment: In my case I wasn't including the font-weight, which is apparently required.

Comment: @MicahMurray I had the exact same problem. Been staring at my screen for the last 15 min haha..

Comment: If some people are still having trouble with this the font-weight may need to be 900. Took an hour before I realized this on my particular issue...

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49754892/8620333 (to fix the font-weight issue)

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Your `Unicode` is wrong `f107`

```css
a::after {
  content: "\f007";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<a>User</a>
<i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i>
```

Or in other case, `font-weight: 900;` will save you. Some icons in font awesome 5 not working without `font-weight: 900;`.

```
a::after {
  content: "\f007";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: Work it. but for use f107 icon (avaiable only solid free) use [code] font-awesome/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
font-awesome/css/fa-solid.css" rel="stylesheet" />[/code]

Comment: @CarmeloValenti But i used `All` version, it should work, but it still not working.

Comment: It's a bug. including all icon, are not shown the icons "solid" that are not present in the "regular" package, so you have to exclude the (few) "regular" icons if you want to use all the "solid"

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem. @Carmelo, could you elaborate your answer better to make us understand?

Comment: I was banging my head on this for hours, font-weight: 900;is the thing! thanks

Comment: font-weight to the rescue. AHhhh, wish i had come across this before. Would have saved me hours trying to figure this out!

Comment: +1 I needed single-quotes on `font-family` \o/ 

MacOS Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Thank you! I was desperate for solution. Works like charm.

Comment: Thank you. Even for `Font Awesome Free 5.13.0`, I still needed to add `font-weight: 900` to make icons like `f107` or `f106` work.

Answer (score 109):

Strangely you must put the '**font-weight: 900**' in some icons so that it shows them.

```
#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse:after {
  content: '\f107';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free'; 
  font-weight: 900; /* Fix version 5.0.9 */
}
```

Comment: Woah! Thanks for that 5.0.9 font-weight fix. That was the only thing missing in my code.

Comment: This already fixed on updated version with `.fa, .fas {
    font-weight: 900;
}`

Comment: Awesome! I'm using 5.1.0, still had to solve this with `font-weight:900;`

Comment: It's because the font weight is called in the `.fa, .fas` classes. If you're doing a custom class, including `:before` or `:after` pseudo classes, then it seems we still have to apply the `font-weight: 900;` value.

Comment: Even on 5.13.0, I had to add `font-weight: 900` for fixing it. Thank you!

Answer (score 26):

The problem is in the `font-weight`.
For `Font Awesome 5` you have to use `{font-weight:900}`

Answer (score 15):

Using the fontawesome-all.css file: Changing the "Brands" font-family from "Font Awesome 5 Free" to "Font Awesome 5 Brands" fixed the issues I was having.

I can't take all of the credit - I fixed my own local issue right before looking at the CDN version: https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css

They've got the issue sorted out on the CDN as well.

```css
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot");
    src: url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff") format("woff"), url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }

    .fab {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands'; }
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot");
  src: url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff") format("woff"), url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }
```

Answer (score 7):

Requiring 900 weight is not a weirdness but a intentional restriction added by FontAwesome (since they share the same unicode but just different font-weight) so that you are not hacking your way into using the 'solid' and 'light' icons, most of which are available only in the paid 'Pro' version.

Answer (score 6):

Since FontAwesome 5, you have to enable a new "searchPseudoElements" option to use FontAwesome icons this way:

```
<script>
  window.FontAwesomeConfig = {
    searchPseudoElements: true
  }
</script>
```

See also this question: [Font awesome 5 on pseudo elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712987/font-awesome-5-on-pseudo-elements) and the new Font Awesome API: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/font-awesome-api

Additionaly, change font-family in your CSS code to

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Regular";
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll just add that I needed to place this script ABOVE the kit script

Answer (score 6):

I had tried all above the solutions for **Font Awesome 5** but it wasn't working for me. :(

**Finally, I got a solution!**

Just use `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";` in your CSS instead of using `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free OR Solids OR Brands";`

Answer (score 4):

I didn't want to use the 'all' version, so searched the '`fontawesome-all.min.css`' file (previously included in the header) for 'family' tag and found at the end a declaration `@font-face{font-family:**Font Awesome\ 5 Free**;font-style:normal;`

So, in the stylesheet for an element where I wanted to use the **`content: "\f0c8";`** code, I've added (or changed to) `font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;` and it worked.

```
.frb input[type="checkbox"] ~ label:before {
    font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
    content: "\f0c8";
    font-weight: 900;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did similar but omitted font-weight: 900 which caused some icons not to work. This version seems a mess since it's not very backwards compatible, with some icons even getting new codes.

Answer (score 4):

Strangely you have to include the font-family and the font-weight for it to work. 
Here is what worked for me:

```css
.second-section-header::after {
    content: "\f259";
    font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

From there, you can begin adding any styles that you want.

Let's say:

```css
.second-section-header::after {
    content: "\f259";
    font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

IF it's still not working for you, I had forgotten to add the `fa-ul` class onto the parent (UL) element:

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
```

Together with the 2 bits of advice provided already by others:

```
a) font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
b) font-weight: 900;
```

solved it for me.

FWIW, the include in my `<head>` tags is just:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

And I am using this with React and Preact. No need for any special React npm installs or components.

Comment: In my case, with Ver 5.20, the upper layer having a `font-weight: 500` resulted Font Awesome not display. Adding itself a `font-weight: N!important` where `N > 500` brings it back. Guess it is the way Font Awesome rendering cause some conflict.

Answer (score 2):

npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free

My Sccs:

```
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims";
```

It worked fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

the solution is call it like normal font:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free-Regular-400";
src: url(../fonts/Font%20Awesome%205%20Free-Regular-400.otf) format("opentype");}
```

Answer (score 1):

that's probably about pricing model... ;)

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use

```
Solid    Free           fas   <i class="fas fa-camera"></i> 
Regular  Pro Required   far   <i class="far fa-camera"></i> 
Light    Pro Required   fal   <i class="fal fa-camera"></i> 
Brands   Free           fab   <i class="fab fa-font-awesome"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

- Integrate `fontawesome-all.css`
- At the end of file Search the second @font-face and replace

  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';

With

```
font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 FreeR';
```

And replace:

```
.far {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 400; }
```

With

```
.far {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 FreeR';
  font-weight: 400; }
```

Comment: If you have  a new solution, please update your previous answer and delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **SVG with JavaScript** you need to enable this because it's disabled by default. Use

`<script data-search-pseudo-elements ... >`

inside your script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `fas` class.

Like:

```
  <i class="fas fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
```

Without the `fas` the icon will not be loaded

Answer (score 0):

If it's still not working for you you should be able to see the code line in your page source (Right Click -> select "View Page Source") where you have imported the FontAwesome stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

If you click on that, it will open the stylesheet in a new tab. In the top part of the stylesheet you will be able to see the name of the font family.

[image: Top part of the FontAwesome stylesheet]

Then you can change the font-family only for the icons which are breaking with the new font used in the web page.

```
#primary-menu .fa-angle-down:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
    /* Changing the icons to FontAwesome font to stop breaking when the font is changed in the site */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to set `searchPseudoElements` to to true to get it working in Angular5.

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome';
...
fontawesome.config.searchPseudoElements = true;
...
content: "\f12a";
font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Solid';
```