# Font Awesome 5 on pseudo elements shows square instead of icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, pseudo-element, font-awesome-5

I am trying to change the content of a `span` with a Font Awesome icon directly from the CSS page but can't seem to make it work properly.

1) I have imported FA from the documentation and in the `<head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5SOiIsAziJl6AWe0HWRKTXlfcSHKmYV4RBF18PPJ173Kzn7jzMyFuTtk8JA7QQG1" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

2) My html looks like this :

```
<span class='myClass'>Movies</span>
```

3) Let's now say I would like to change the content of the span with an icon directly from the CSS Page.

My css currently looks like this but it isn't working, it gives me a square instead of the icon.

```css
.myClass {
  font-size:25px;
}

.myClass::after {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  content: '\f008';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css">
<span class='myClass'></span>
```

Funny thing is that it looks like it is working with some icons. If I test with `content: '\f007';` it works. Any idea why?

(And if you wonder why I want to change the icon directly in the CSS, it is because I am using media queries so I can't add it directly in the HTML page)

Comment: what code of icon is this ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif this is a movie icon

Comment: can you share it's link wthin the fontawesome site ... so we verify it to which package it belong

Comment: He did, in his first embedded section.

Comment: @Roberrrt i meant the link of the icon ;) not the Font Awesome lib

Comment: Here is the icon link https://fontawesome.com/icons/film?style=solid

Comment: @Roberrrt something like this : https://fontawesome.com/icons/address-book?style=solid to verify the package as it may be a part of the Pro ones

Answer (score 62, accepted):

<sup>If you are using the **JS+SVG version** read this: [Font Awesome 5 shows empty square when using the JS+SVG version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48753688/8620333)</sup>

You need to add

### `font-weight:900`

```css
.myClass {
  font-size:45px;
}

.myClass::after {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  content: "\f008";
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
<span class='myClass'></span>
```

The `regular` version of the icon, defined by the default `font-weight`, is PRO so it will show an empty square. What you need is the `solid` version:

https://fontawesome.com/icons/film?style=solid

[image: CSS fontawesome 5 pseud element font weight]

**Why the other icon is working?**

Because the `\f007` is this icon : https://fontawesome.com/icons/user?style=regular and as you can see, the `regular` one is not PRO and is included in the free package so you don't need to specify a `font-weight`. You only need to specify it when you want to show the `solid` version.

```css
.myClass::after {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  content: "\f007";
  visibility: visible;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.myClass-1::after {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  content: "\f007";
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css">
<span class='myClass'>Solid </span>
<br>
<span class='myClass-1'>Regular </span>
```

---

As a side note, all the `light` and `duotone` versions are included in the Pro package so will always show empty square whataver the `font-weight` used

---

You can check the documentation for more details : https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements

[image: Font Awesome 5 - pseudo element]

---

Related questions

[Font Awesome 5 shows empty square when using the JS+SVG version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48753688/8620333)

[Font Awesome 5 unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49766325/8620333)

[Font Awesome 5, why is css content not showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49690006/8620333)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation ! Do you know what `font-weight` I would need to use if the `light` version would have been free ?

Comment: @nsayer all the `light` icons are PRO so there is no font-weight for them in the free package ;) you can only use them if you get the PRO one

Comment: @nsayer for a lighter render, you may try text-stroke, see answer below for testing ;)

Answer (score 1):

from your comment :

> Awesome, thanks for the explanation ! Do you know what font-weight I would need to use if the light version would have been free ?

test `text-stroke` with a transparent color to get a thinner render :

```css
.myClass {
  font-size: 45px;
}

.myClass::after {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  content: "\f008";
  font-weight: 900;
  -webkit-text-stroke;
  transparent 0.2em;
}

.myClass+.myClass::after {
  -webkit-text-stroke: white 0.02em;
}

.bis {
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
<span class='myClass'></span>
<span class='myClass'></span>
<span class='myClass bis '></span>
<u>
<span class='myClass bis '></span></u>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list-style-image: url("../../media/examples/rocket.svg");
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image