# Is it possible in Font Awesome to switch between the "far" and "fas" data-prefix with the CSS content attribute?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

1. I am using the CSS content attribute because it loads faster than the  tags.
2. The "fa-user" icon class has two sets of icons, i.e. "far" and "fas" but, they share the same Unicode "\f007". This is a problem.
3. The result that is obtained has just one drawback. The icons load a couple of seconds after the page does. Hence, it messes with the UX.
4. Using the  tag adds up to commented HTML markup.

> So, is there a way I can still use CSS content attributes and switch between the `"far"` and `"fas"` classes?

Any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between the `fas` and the `far` of an icon is the `font-weight` so to switch between both you simply need to adjust the `font-weight`:

```css
.icon {
    font-family:"Font Awesome\ 5 Free";
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    line-height: 1;
}
.icon:before {
  content:"\f007";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css">
<span class="icon" style="font-weight:300"></span>
<span class="icon" style="font-weight:900"></span>
```

Here is another related question: [Font Awesome shows square instead of icon when used directly in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754892/font-awesome-shows-square-instead-of-icon-when-used-directly-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome 5 has [asynchronous loading indicators](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/performance-and-security#async-loading-indicators) that allow you to add css to the icon containers while they load so you can make sure that they do not shift your layout.

There is no need to use the css solution for this. And either way, the css also has to load external resources so this could take a while as well.