# Font awesome icon in placeholder not showing up unless font weight set to 600

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5, fontawesome-4.4.0

I upgraded from Font Awesome 4.4 to 5 and I went from using the downloaded files to the CDN.

The fonts work fine, but when using an icon in my search field input placeholder it not showing like I want:

```css
input {
  font-family: Arial, 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #777;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

This won't show<br>
<input placeholder=" Location"><br>

This one is showing<br>
<input placeholder=" Location" style="font-weight:600"><br>
```

The problem I'm having is it only shows up if the font weight of the search field is 600 or more! If I set the font weight to 500 the font icon disappears!

The issue seems to be related to the fact that the regular icon belong to the PRO version and I can only use the solid one (as explained here : [Font Awesome shows square instead of icon when used directly in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754892/font-awesome-shows-square-instead-of-icon-when-used-directly-in-css))

Is there any way to use the icon as a placehodler (as I want it to disappear when typing a text) BUT without making the text bold. The icon can be bold, but not the text.

Here is the website where you can also see the result:

Comment: yes, if the Regular version of this icon is not free

Comment: the duplicate will give the explanation and you can verify here : https://fontawesome.com/icons/search?style=solid

Comment: if that's true, is there a way to keep the 'search' icon bold but make the other part of the search field placeholder 'Location' a regular weight?

Comment: make it outside the input in this case then play with CSS to make it there, I don't see another way

Comment: did they change this with the newer versions? I didn't have this issue with version 4.4?

Comment: Yes it's new, as in V5 we have PRO ones that you need to pay for ... in the V4 all of them are free. So the PRO ones will not be visible. They need to make money :)

Comment: do you work for FA?

Comment: no I don't work for them :)

Comment: thanks! you mentioned using CSS to make it outside the search field, then play with it! Can you give me a better explanation of what you would do to achieve this?

Comment: here is a quick example : https://jsfiddle.net/8uv0pkwd/

Comment: right, I understand that can be acomplished, but I meant a way to include the 'search' icon as part of the placeholder, so that it dissappears when you focus on the search field

Comment: actually I don't know if it's possible .. but am gonna edit your question to highlight this particular issue and re-open it, maybe you will get some ideas

Comment: cool thanks! much appreciated

Comment: ok it's edited and opened, feel free to re-adjust the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is to create the placeholder as element outside the input in order to easily isolate the icon, then you can simulate the placeholder effect by playing with the `focus` state and some `z-index`.

```css
input,
label span {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #777;
  font-size: 18px;
}

label {
  position: relative;
}

label>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
  cursor: auto;
}

input {
  position: relative;
}

input:focus {
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Or 
input:focus + span {
  display:none;
}

*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css">

<label>
<input  style="font-weight:600">
<span><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Location</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think mixing the font icon and the standard font that you are using for the input might not be the best way to go. For your use case I would recommend separating out the icon from the rest of the input like this:

```
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Location" />
  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
</div>
```

I've made an [example here](https://jsbin.com/yumuxex/edit?html,css,output) that also has some example CSS. To match your current implementation, the icon will also hide on input focus, but this doesn't always need to be the case.

There is also a built in way to do this in Bootstrap which I can see is being used on your example site:

V4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/

V3: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups