# How to integrate Fontawesome 6 Pro self hosted icons with HTML5 canvas?

Tags: css, html5-canvas, font-awesome, webfonts

I have a react project and hosted the fonts by myself following [this guide](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/webfonts#add-font-awesome-files-to-your-project)

my folders looks like this:

```
src
|___fonts
|   |___css
|   |   |___fontawesome.css
|   |   |___regular.css
|   |___webfonts
|       |___fa-regular-400.woff2
|       |___fa-regular-400.ttf
|___App.css
|___App.ts
|___...
```

And in my App.js i have the following code:

```
import React, {useLayoutEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './fonts/css/fontawesome.css';
import './fonts/css/regular.css';
function App() {

  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    canvas = canvasRef.current as HTMLCanvasElement;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    draw();
  }, []);

  const draw = (): void => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.font = '100px Font Awesome 6 Pro';
    ctx.fillText('\uf111', 100, 100);
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <canvas id={'game_canvas'} ref={canvasRef} width={500} height={500}>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</canvas>
      <p>&#xf111;</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App.ts;
```

and inside App.css

```
.App {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Pro';
}
.App #game_canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Note that after the canvas i'm rendering a `<p></p>` tag. That tag is using the HTML syntax for unicode, while in the `ctx.fillText` function i'm using the other syntax.

The result is I see the icon rendered in the `<p></p>` tag but not the icon inside the canvas context.

[Inside canvas the icon is broken, but the fa-circle-icon can be seen outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqpnv.png)

I tried alternating into several syntaxes for unicode, and also integrating the typography with Styled components following [this guide](https://dev.to/alaskaa/how-to-import-a-web-font-into-your-react-app-with-styled-components-4-1dni) with no good results.

The expected behavior is to be able to render an icon from a self hosted webfont inside a canvas 2D context.

Comment: Don't forget to clean up your `requestAnimationFrame` in the useEffect return.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for the heads up! I modified the code to return a function that calls cancelAnimationFrame in the useLayoutEffect

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue!, I simply forgot the double quotes in the font name defining the `ctx.font` property

```
ctx.font = '100px Font Awesome 6 Pro' //wrong
ctx.font = '100px "Font Awesome 6 Pro"' //correct
```

Found the issue while looking closely at this: [How can I use FontAwesome icons on a html 5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54615721/how-can-i-use-fontawesome-icons-on-a-html-5-canvas)