# Font Awesome 5 icons not rendering when used as font-family in CSS

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

There are numerous posts about this but solutions given thus far don't work for me:

- [fontawesome 5 font-family not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788847/fontawesome-5-font-family-not-work)
- https://theme-fusion.com/forums/topic/font-awesome-not-working-after-5-6-2-update/

Using Font Awesome 5 Free version from a CDN. I've set up a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ej2r8kpy/

This renders icons properly. For example using the markup:

```
<i class="fas fa-bullhorn fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

I get this:

[image]

This is correct so I know Font Awesome is working.

I'm trying to change the breadcrumb separator in Bootstrap 4 from the default " / " to a Font Awesome icon.

So, I've tried some solutions such as:

```
.breadcrumb-item+.breadcrumb-item::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Free";
    content: "\f105";
}
```

In the above case, `\f105` is the Unicode copied from the icon I want: https://fontawesome.com/icons/angle-right?style=solid

However, when I use this in breadcrumbs it renders without the icon and a "square" which is what happens when it can't render Font Awesome icons:

[image]

The updated markup is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ej2r8kpy/1/

Why is this not working?

Comment: Where are you loading the font in the fiddle?

Comment: @Paulie_D click on the Resources tab and you'll see it's loading `https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/js/all.js` This is all Font Awesome supply as their way to use it from a CDN (no `.css` files are included)

Comment: The right angle is appearing for me in your fiddle. You could try adding the `font-weight` property - as I think the free version of font awesome might require it.

Comment: That's really odd. It works in Firefox but not Chrome

Comment: @Andy: It doesn't work for me in Firefox Developer edition FYI.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8xozrvau/ (1) font-weight issue (first duplicate) (2) JS issue with pseudo element (second duplicate)

Comment: @Adrift can you explain why you reponed the question? ... all the details are within the duplcate (including the display:none)

Comment: It was a mistake, I closed it again with the relevant duplicate question. Sorry.