# Font Awesome icon not showing up for some reason

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I am trying to use font Awesome icon as Pseudo-Element with content property so that importing their whole library is not needed.

The output shows up a  squared box instead of the actual icon .
I think i am missing something here

```
<div>
<span class="icon"></span>Text After icon
</div>
```

```
.icon::before {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f007";
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I think it needs to be  font-family:”Font Awesome \5 Free”.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788847/fontawesome-5-font-family-not-work

Comment: did you add the <script> link from font awesome

Comment: @PavelHasala well i changed  the font-family as you told   still its not working - https://jsbin.com/sinufuciru/edit?output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed your code by adding font awesome, please try this:

```
<div>
<span class="icon"></span>Text After icon
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
 B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: But as far i know , linking their Stylesheet and then using pseudo + content don't go together.   We either use one of them , don't we ?

Comment: Dear Badal, You must use both concurrent.

Comment: well i tried your code. Still icon not showing up - https://jsbin.com/hakufaqajo/edit?output

Comment: I've edited my code ( Changed url ), please try again. @BadalSingh