# Getting error loading font awesome 5 in WP site

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, font-awesome, pseudo-element

I have used font awesome 5 on my website! It was working fine when I have used it on html but when I tried to use this on CSS using pseudo it was not working properly! The icon was not loading

```css
.ex-loadmore .loadmore-exbt {
      border: none;
      color: $cerulean;
      font-family: $secondary-font;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 48px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #3A7DC0;
      padding: 0 30px !important;

      &::after {
          content: "\f04b";
          font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
      }

      &:hover {
          color: #fff !important;
          background: #3A7DC0 !important;
          padding: 0 30px !important;
      }
}
```

```html
function emailagency_assets() {

wp_enqueue_style(
$handle = 'google_fonts', 
$src = '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap'
);

wp_enqueue_style(
$handle = 'fontAwesome', 
$src = '//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css'
);

wp_enqueue_style(
$handle = 'bootstrap', 
$src = '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'
);

if ( is_rtl() ) {
wp_enqueue_style( 'mfn-rtl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css' );
}

// Enqueue the child stylesheet
wp_dequeue_style( 'style' );
wp_enqueue_style( 
$handle = 'style', 
$src = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/dist/css/style.css' 
);

wp_enqueue_script( 
$handle = 'font_awesome_script',
$src = '//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/js/all.js'
);

wp_enqueue_script( 
$handle = 'boot1',
$src = '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'
);

wp_enqueue_script( 
$handle = 'boot2',
$src = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js'
);

wp_enqueue_script( 
$handle = 'boot3',
$src = '//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'
);
}

add_action(
$tag = 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 
$function_to_add = 'emailagency_assets'
);
```

I have tried font awesome 4 it worked but not sure why version 5 is not working! 
Any kind of help would be very appreciatable!

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712987/font-awesome-5-on-pseudo-elements

Comment: Thanks I have tried this but it was working for brand icons only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to add `font-weight: 900;` to your pseudo element. [Docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements) says that Free Plan uses only `Bold` icons, it could be the issue.

`\f04b` looks like the one from Solid set of icons, so it uses only 900 "Bold" weight using Free Plan.

400 "Regular" is possible to use with Brand set of icons using Free Plan.

```css
.custom-span {
  display: block;
  padding: 40px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.custom-span:before {
  content: "\f04b";
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
}
```

```html
<link href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <span class="custom-span"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut consequatur, dignissimos eos esse magnam neque provident rem? Ea, maiores praesentium? Ad cum doloremque dolores, error illum non porro temporibus voluptas.</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```js
<script>
  window.FontAwesomeConfig = {
    searchPseudoElements: true
  }
</script>
```

```css
.class:before{
  display: none;
  content: "\f16c";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
}
```

Comment: Other types: Font Awesome 5   Solid or Regular or Light or Brands

Comment: I have tried this for solids but it is not working, unfortunately!
https://www.screencast.com/t/05Xouj8WXRo

Comment: I think it will work without script! 
Only you have to add font-weight in css for regular icons