# Font awesome unicode some icons not displaying

Tags: unicode, font-awesome

I am using unicode as per cheetsheet:  https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet/free/solid

I tried changing font-weight as per answer here but it hasnt helped: [Font awesome 5 on pseudo elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712987/font-awesome-5-on-pseudo-elements)

Maybe the issue is in css I linked? I dont know where to get other css version if there is newer.

```css
.icon {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', 'Font Awesome 5 Regular', 'Font Awesome 5 Brands', 'Arial';
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div><span class="icon brand">&#xf834;</span>airbnb</div>
<div><span class="icon">&#xf42c;</span>amazon-pay</div>
<div><span class="icon">&#xe059;</span>bacteria</div>
```

Comment: What icons were you expecting for Airbnb and Bacteria?

Comment: Icons that are on the cheetsheet linked above.

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode for the first and last icons are incorrect if you are using just Font Awesome 5.

- `&#xf834;` doesn't exist in any icon library or in Unicode at all.
- `&#xe059;` matches with `glyphicon-facetime-video` from Bootstrap Icons and `replay_10` from Google Material Icons. The reason why it didn't show up as either is because Bootstrap Icons needs the class `glyphicon` and Google Material needs the class `material-icons`.

Moreover Font Awesome also needs a class assigned to it's element. The CSS class in OP code, `.icon` is sufficient (it has the FA `font-family` property), but if you don't have that, the built-in classes are adequate as well (free versions are: `fa`, `fas`, and `fab`).

|  | HTML |
| --- | --- |
| With Unicode | `<i class="fas">&#xf780;</i>` |
| Without Unicode | `<i class="fas fa-biohazard"></i>` |

```css
:root,
body {
  font: 2ch/1 'Segoe UI'
}

.fab,
.fas {
  margin: 2px 3px;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', 'Font Awesome 5 Regular', 'Font Awesome 5 Brands', 'Arial';
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div><i class="fas fa-bed"></i> Airbnb Locator</div>
<div><i class="fab">&#xf42c;</i> Amazon Pay</div>
<div><i class="fas fa-biohazard"></i> COV-ID Status</div>
```

Comment: f834 does exist, go to cheetsheet linked above and to brands tab.  e059 is in free tab.

Comment: The reason the dont show because I can see they are not present in here https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css. If I download font awesome5 library from their website I can see css file having these symbols. Maybe there is newer version of css available online?

Comment: I used https://www.w3schools.com/icons/icons_reference.asp#header_0 Doesn't really matter, as long as you use class `fas` and `fab` or even `fa` you shouldm't have any problems...you did see my example, right? In fact, as long as the element has this CSS it will work: `font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free',  'Font Awesome 5 Brands'`

Comment: I am working with unicode,  I dont want fa classes.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you need to use the link of FontAwesome either CDN in index.html(main file) or import css in style.css

cdn: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">`

import in css file: `@import url("https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css");`

```
eg li::before
selector::before{     
    content: "\f007";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
}
```